# Unparseable date: "1.8082"

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I try to get a xml-response from service with retrofit and SimpleXml.

```
<DailyExRates Date="10/19/2021">
<Currency Id="440">
<NumCode>036</NumCode>
<CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
<Scale>1</Scale>
<Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
<Rate>1.8081</Rate>
</Currency>
<Currency Id="510">
<NumCode>051</NumCode>
<CharCode>AMD</CharCode>
<Scale>1000</Scale>
<Name>Армянских драмов</Name>
<Rate>5.1086</Rate>
</Currency>
</DailyExRates>
```

and my pojo classes:

```
    @Root(strict = false, name = "DailyExRates ")
data class DailyExRates constructor(

    @field:ElementList(inline = true)
    var Currency: ArrayList<Currency>? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "Date", required = false)
    var Date: Long? = null,
)
```

```
data class Currency constructor (
    @field:Element(name = "NumCode", required = false)
    var NumCode: Int? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "CharCode", required = false)
    var CharCode: String? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "Scale", required = false)
    var Scale: Int? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "Name", required = false)
    var Name: String? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "Rate", required = false)
    var Rate: Date? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "Id", required = false)
    var Id: Int? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "text", required = false)
    var text: String? = null
)
```

I have a problem: Unparseable date: "1.8082"

date fromat in xml-response is MM-dd-yyyy

Comment: Maybe change `var Rate: Date? = null,` to `var Rate: Double? = null`

Comment: It's not working

Comment: It looks like something actually treated the / as division, then tried to parse the result.

As an aside-  if you can change that date format, do.  Is 1/2/2020 January 2nd or February 1st?  You can't tell from the data, and outside North America nobody uses month first.  There are standards for sending dates that avoid that problem.  Generally you send dates as YYYY-MM-DD so you can directly compare the two strings to see which comes first.

Answer (score 0):

Rate should be a double.  The date is DailyExRates, a separate field.  You may need to tell it what the date format is as well-  the format you use, as I commented above, is ambiguous and it may guess wrong if you don't specify.

Comment: Can you describe the solution with code? Because I'm beginner and I don't understand what should I do

Comment: @Mikhail Change these: 1) `var Date: Long? = null` -> `var Date: String? = null`, 2) `var Rate: Date? = null` -> `var Rate: Double? = null`, 3) `var Id: Int? = null` -> `var Id: String? = null`.